# TypeError in python script

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

I am getting a TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting error in my python script.
I am trying to write a cardid from an RFC Chip into a database including the current time (which works) and get a select query to give me the corresponding user (which does not work)

"mysql.py"

```
def insertReading(tagId,action):
db = connect()
cur = db.cursor()
currentTime=strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime())
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO readings (tagId, time, action) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(tagId,currentTime,action))
db.commit()
cur.execute("SELECT name,surname FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT userId FROM cards WHERE tagId=%s LIMIT 1)",(tagId))
row = cur.fetchone();
db.close()
```

My error message is the following:

```
File "/home/pi/SPI-Py/RPi.GPIO-0.6.4/attendance/mysql.py", line 33, in insertReading
    cur.execute("SELECT name,surname FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT userId FROM cards WHERE tagId=%s LIMIT 1)",(tagId))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 210, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The cur.execute("SELECT name,surname FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT userId FROM cards WHERE tagId=%s LIMIT 1)",(tagId)) seems to be the problem and I can't figure out why :(
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cur.execute()` requires a tuple, list or dictionary of arguments to be inserted into the query string. In this case `(tagId)` is not a tuple, it is evaluated as an integer (or whatever data type `tagid` is).

```
>>> tagid = 123
>>> (tagid)
123
>>> type((tagid))
<type 'int'>
>>> (tagid,)
(123,)
>>> type((tagid,))
<type 'tuple'>
```

So use a tuple like this: `(tagId,)`. Tbe comma tells Python that a tuple should be created.